# Verificar se conexão de internet ativa

Tags: visual-basic-6

Existe alguma função que retorne se existe uma conexão de internet ativa?
Digo, não somente a placa de rede conectada, mas sim, uma conexão ativa efetivamente.

Vlw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É que essa solução é com chamada de API e depende de DLLs específicas. Uma outra solução é usar o componente INET e codificar assim:

```
Wresposta = Inet1.OpenURL("http://www.brasil.gov.br/")
if Wresposta = "" then
   msgbox("Fora da NET")
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Declare Function Ping Lib "iphlpapi" _
Alias "#65" (ByVal pInternetProtocol As Long, pNumberOfCalls As Long, _
ByVal pMaxNumberOfCalls As Long, lTime As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ConvertStringToIP Lib "wsock32" _
Alias "#10" (ByVal stoip As String) As Long

Function MyPing(sIPAddr As String) As Boolean
Dim IP As Long, pNumCalls As Long, lTime As Long
IP = ConvertStringToIP(sIPAddr)
MyPing = (Ping(IP, pNumCalls, 15, lTime) = 1): End Function

'Chamando a Função'
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim Result As Boolean: Result = MyPing("200.158.24.129")
If Result = True Then
MsgBox "OK"
Else
MsgBox "Não Respondeu": End If
End Sub
```

Comment: está indicando erro: Bad DLL calling convertion
nesta linha: MyPing = (Ping(IP, pNumCalls, 15, lTime) = 1): End Function

Comment: ok. entendi. achei mais facil pelo INET. já utilizo para outros fins na aplicação. obrigado